# Reconfigure certificates or edit certificate information

Tags: apache2, lets-encrypt, ssl-certificate-errors

Necessary details first:

OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
System: Digital Ocean droplet

I attempted to set up a self-signed certificate for SSL verification using Let's Encrypt. In either haste or misunderstanding, my common name was set as my command prompt instead of the domain name. I used https://sslshopper.com to assess the situation, which is where I discovered the discrepancy.  I have searched up and down for remedies to this, though I have yet to come across one that has helped.  I also saw there is the possibility of issuing too many certificates, which can result in extended invalidity.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to edit the information? If so, how?
2. If it's not possible to edit the information what is the best remedy to the situation, short of completely destroying and rebuilding the droplet entire (there isn't much there right now, so that's not off the table)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't rebuild your server because an SSL certificate isn't correct, you issue another certificate. However, in this case, I think you've taken an incorrect approach.

You don't need an http certificate in order to issue a Let's Encrypt certificate. That would make it almost impossible to get a certificate, putting the cart before the horse. Let's Encrypt connects to your server using http to validate ownership.

Here's my Nginx configuration that I use for Let's Encrypt, which has worked well for a couple of years. I don't define a rule that would do the same thing in https, so I know http works. I don't have an Apache config to share sorry, but there will be many examples online.

```
# Redirect all variations to https://www domain, other than let's encrypt validation
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  # Let's Encrypt certificates with Acmetool
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    alias /var/www/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://www.photographerstechsupport.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Let's Encrypt limits you to [20 live certificates per week](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/). There's also a LE [staging environment](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/) which lets you issue 30,000 certificates per week. The best approach is to use the staging environment while you're testing, then switch to issue a live certificate.